# Unit test for functions drilled down

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I had a file with the following handler passing it down to the child component

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(returnsReducer, initialState);
const selectItemHandler = (salesOrderLineId: number) => {
  dispatch({ type: SET_SELECTED_ITEMS, salesOrderLineId });
};


const selectQuantityHandler = (
  selectedQuantity: number,
  salesOrderLineId: number
) => {
  const item = { salesOrderLineId, selectedQuantity };
  dispatch({ type: SET_SELECTED_QUANTITY, item });
};
```

Passing it down like this:

```
const renderEligibleItems = () => {
    return eligibleItems.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <ProductTileWrapper
          key={i}
          {...item}
          onItemSelect={selectItemHandler}
          onQuantityChange={selectQuantityHandler}
          selectedItems={selectedItems}
        />
      );
    });
  };
```

Not able to write unit testing for this(using react-testing library with jest), any suggestions on how I should approach?

Comment: What do you mean *"not able"*? What did you try, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the test code you have tried to write?

Answer (score 0):

i guess was confusing integration testing with unit testing. We can do integration testing and achieve testing of the following
We have to look for the element changed when the following functions are triggered.
Example

```
it("should make the checkbox checked", async () => {
    render(<OrdersReturnsBasePage />);
    const checkbox = screen
      .getAllByTestId("checkbox")[0]
      .querySelector("input");
    await fireEvent.click(checkbox);
    expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();
  });
```